# helm values.yaml - use value from another node

Tags: kubernetes-helm

so for example i have

```
database:
  name: x-a2d9f4
  replicaCount: 1
  repository: mysql
  tag: 5.7
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  tier: database

app:
  name: x-576a77
  replicaCount: 1
  repository: wordpress
  tag: 5.2-php7.3
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  tier: frontend

global:
  namespace: x-c0ecdb9f

env:
  name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
  value:
```

and I want to do something like this

```
env:
  name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
  value: {{ .Values.database.name | lower }}
```

All these are examples from the same `values.yaml`

is this possible in Helm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this [using the 'tpl' function](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks.md#using-the-tpl-function)

> The tpl function allows developers to evaluate strings as templates inside a template. This is useful to pass a template string as a value to a chart or render external configuration files. Syntax: {{ tpl TEMPLATE_STRING VALUES }}

**values.yaml**

```
database:
  name: x-a2d9f4

env:
  name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
  value: "{{ .Values.database.name | upper }}"
```

**configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  some: {{ tpl .Values.env.value . }}
```

**output:**

`> helm template .`

```
# Source: mychart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: release-name-configmap
data:
  some: X-A2D9F4
```

Comment: in `values.yaml` you have `{{ .Values.database ... }}` will that access a neighbor node called `database`?

Comment: Yes, it will access the database section above, however you will need to include it between " " and call tpl in your service/deployment definition.